# Finding the largest possible epsilon?

Tags: calculus

I am not sure where to go when trying to solve this question. Please see question below:

Find the maximal $\epsilon > 0$ such that whenever $|x-1| < \epsilon$, then $|\frac{1}{x} - 1| < 1.$

**Edit: My approach**

$$|\frac{1}{x} - 1| < 1$$
$$| \frac{1-x}{x} | < 1$$
$$| 1-x| <|x|$$
$$1 < 2x $$
$$x > \frac{1}{2}$$

So now, when I plug in $x > \frac{1}{2}$ to $|x-1| < \epsilon$ I get $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: There is no $\delta$ here, as I see. This is not a question about limits. Do you see how the expression $|\frac{1}{x}-1|$ is related to $|x-1|$?

Comment: Hint: $|\frac{1}{x} - 1| < 1\iff(1-x)^2<x^2$.

Comment: @AnneBauval That's even easier. I solved the equation $|x-1|<|x|$.

Comment: To paraphrase Freud, sometimes epsilon is just epsilon.

Comment: OP, as I understand you have to check when $|x-1|<\epsilon$ always implies $|\frac{1}{x}-1|<1$. So the largest $\epsilon$ for which this is always true is $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$. For larger $\epsilon$ we might take the point $x=\frac{1}{2}$ which satisfies the first condition, but not the second.

Comment: @DavidK: True, though I feel it's more playing the role of $\delta$ here, with $1$ playing a *tour de force* triple role as $a$, $L$, *and* $\varepsilon$ (in its younger days, possibly), and introducing $1/x$ as $f(x)$.

Comment: @Mark, I am not sure I follow your point. Could you please clarify?

Comment: @BrianTung Considering that "find the largest possible value" of either $\epsilon$ or $\delta$ really shouldn't be an objective of any delta-epsilon proof, I think the first comment applies: this is not about limits, so there's no mapping at all to the usual delta-epsilon notation.

Comment: Your approach is correct.  Your solution is almost correct.  As stated by @Mark the correct answer is $\varepsilon = \frac 12$, not (as you have written) $\varepsilon \gt \frac 12$.

Comment: @AnneBauval Yeah, I meant your equation is easier. (a bit, but still) Sorry if it was unclear.

Comment: @ArtemisF same comment as Robert, plus: to justify $$| 1-x| <|x|\iff1<2x,$$ my favorite intermediate step is $(1-x)^2<x^2$ (then, expand the lhs and cancel the $x^2$s).

Comment: And why is this the case: that when $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$ that we achieve the maximal $\epsilon$?

Comment: @DavidK: It's essentially one challenge-response phase in establishing that $\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = 1$ where $f(x) = 1/x$, with the challenge to find the largest $\delta$ such that $\varepsilon = 1$ is satisfied. But my comment was mostly (let us say $80$ percent) tongue in cheek. :-)

Comment: @BrianTung My comment was mostly serious: $\delta$-$\epsilon$ requires one to find **a** $\delta$ such that etc., and there's (usually) no prize for finding the largest one. A lot of students seem to be misled into the idea that a limit proof requires finding a largest $\delta$, which makes their lives harder and says to me that someone has taught them poorly. So it touches a nerve for me whenever an exercise like this question is associated with limits.

Comment: @DavidK: Fair enough! At any rate, I think I won't mislead too many people buried deep in the comment thread.

Answer (score -1):

If $|x- 1|<\epsilon$ then $-\epsilon< x-1< \epsilon$ so $1-\epsilon< x< 1+ \epsilon$.

So $\frac{1}{1+\epsilon}<\frac{1}{x}< \frac{1}{1-\epsilon}$
$\frac{1}{1+\epsilon}- 1<\frac{1}{x}- 1< \frac{1}{1-\epsilon}- 1$
$\frac{-\epsilon}{1+ \epsilon}<\frac{1}{x}- 1<\frac{\epsilon}{1- \epsilon}$

Since $\frac{\epsilon}{1+ \epsilon}< \frac{\epsilon}{1- \epsilon}$ that can be written $\left|\frac{1}{x}- 1\right|< \frac{\epsilon}{1- \epsilon}$.